# jQuery-ui/datepicker doesn't show Rails 4.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to add a calendar to my Rails app so I have a form with a text_field and if I press that field, I want a calendar to be displayed. In order to do that, I'm following Railscasts PRO #213 calendars revised but the calendar is not displayed. I'll show you what I have.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', group: :assets
```

app/assets/javascript/application.js:

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
*= require jquery-ui/datepicker
*= require_self 
*= require_tree .
```

app/views/bookings/new.html.erb:

```
<%= f.label :start_date, "Tour begins on:" %>
<%= f.text_field :start_date, class: "show_calendar" %>
```

app/assets/javascript/bookings.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $('show_calendar').datepicker()
```

Can you find something wrong?

Thank you!!

Comment: Your missing a _dot_ (`.`) in your selector which indicates that it's a class -> `$('.show_calendar').datepicker()`

Comment: Today I discovered a new way to do it and in my opinion it's simpler: <%= f.date_field :start_date %> Thank you anyway! :)